# How to Adjust Brightness in Lubuntu 15.04

Tags: lubuntu, laptop, brightness

I just installed Lubuntu 15.04 on my Toshiba Satellite laptop and can't figure out how to adjust the brightness. I can't find it anywhere and have been looking at other people's questions for an hour trying to figure this out.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=127998.0

Answer (score 1):

This might not fix the problem, but it does provide a workaround.

There is a program called xbacklight that you can install via apt-get, and it allows you to change brightness with a simple interface through the command line.

```
$ sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

The program lets you set the brightness on a scale from 0 to 100. For example, to maximize your brightness, you could do:

```
$ xbacklight -set 100
```

Additionally, if your problem is that your function keys aren't changing the brightness, there might be a problem with your keyboard drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is obvious but have you tried keyboard shortcuts? `F8` or `F9`. Also, you could try to find a keyboard map, which would be especially helpful if you could find one for your laptop model. =) Hope that's helpful =D

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> worked as the keyboard shortcuts for controlling Brightness for me. I am runming Lubuntu 16.04 on a HP probook 6460b.

Comment: OP asked "*Can anyone point me in the right direction?*". Which direction is your answer pointing OP to?